# count number group by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with this format :

```
        sacc_id$                     id$             creation_date
0   001A000000hwvV0IAI  5001200000ZnfUgAAJ  2016-06-07 14:38:02
1   001A000000hwvV0IAI  5001245600ZnfUgAAJ  2016-06-07 15:31:02
2   002A000000hwvV0IAI  5001245600ZnfUgAAJ  2016-06-07 15:41:02
```

I would like to add for this dataframe a count column which count for each sacc_id$ the number id$  during the last 3 months.

I  did like this :

```
df_case = (pd.to_datetime(df_case['creation_date'])
       .value_counts()
       .rename_axis('date')
       .reset_index(name='count'))
```

But it is not completed.

Can you help me please?

thanks

Comment: What does your expected output for this dataframe look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 df_case[pd.to_datetime(df_case['creation_date']) > (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=90)) ].groupby('sacc_id')['id'].count()
```

Comment: Thank you Raju312, it works, but how can make a name of the columns count. I get as result a dataframe with the first column 'sacc_id' and the second column without name.

Comment: in groupby function call, pass as_index=False and then rename the columns as: df.columns = ['sacc_id', 'count']